# how to write a shortcut of same attribute of name and id value in html input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="text" id="motto" name="motto" value="">
```

Instead of writing so long, can I just have some kind of `nameid="motto"` ? 
How to do this in javascript ? I've been doing this with a function in php before, and just curious if there's javascript solution available.

Comment: There's no way to do that in plain HTML.

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a genuine question to me asking for a solution.

Comment: It is possible, but you should use the serverside PHP function. Doing it on the clientside would mean serving invalid HTML in the first place, and imagine JS is disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such `nameid` parameter defined in the HTML specification. So while you could achieve that with javascript you will get broken HTML in the first place. I would not recommend you going that route, but if you decide to go against my recommendation and render broken markup here's what you could do with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').each(function() {
        var nameid = $(this).attr('nameid');
        $(this).attr('id', nameid).attr('name', nameid);
        $(this).removeAttr('nameid');
    });
});
```

Comment: I mean, can I just replace the nameid="motto" with javascript function ? Is it a good idea ?

Comment: Yes, of course, that's exactly what I have shown in my answer.

Comment: Thx. In the end of the day, I think I'll go back to php.

Comment: Sure, that's the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

You mean have a *nameid* attribute in the *HTML* and fix it with *JavaScript* upon page load?

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( // for each
    document.querySelectorAll(*[nameid]), // element with this attribute
    function (e) { // do
        var v = e.getAttribute('nameid'); // get the value
        e.setAttribute('id', v); // set id
        e.setAttribute('name', v); // set name
        e.removeAttribute('nameid'); // remove it
    }
);
```

You should be aware that any HTML with this *nameid* attribute would be **invalid**.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the ID, and you can put this in your javascript to set the names the same:

```
$('input[id]').each(function() { $(this).attr("name", this.id); });
```

Comment: What's gained by the extra overhead?  Saving the programmer from typing out something that still might be required in the spec.